# What does fontification mean in the context of web editors?

Tags: web, editor

I came by the term on http://web-mode.org:

"current HTML element highlighting, element content and tag customized fontification, current indentation column highlighting"

I am however unable to locate any satisfactory definition of its meaning online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think fontification is the font type, font size, bla .....